# Cronjob fails to run a bash script giving an error "aws : command not found"

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, cron, putty

I have a script to invalidate Amazon CloudFront in a .sh file and it works fine when I run it with bash (bash /../filename.sh). I need to invalidate my distribution every thursday, so I wrote a cron job, but it is giving the error "***aws: command not found***".

This is my cron job 
      45 10 * * 2 /usr/bin/bash /var/www/cms/file.sh
What I am missing? Why the cron job is failing when bash could run the script?

Comment: Add the full path to the aws command with in the script

Comment: aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXXXXXXXXX --paths '/*'   - I am not able to find the relative path to aws. aws --version is working, but there is no such thing in /usr/bin where all the other installed utilities are there

Comment: Type "whereis aws"

Comment: Got it. It was inside /usr/local/ and after specifying the path in the script, it worked. Thanks a lot @ Raman Sailopal

Answer (score 1):

This is because your system depends on an environment variable for places where to search for executable files and that variable is not set in the cron sessions. This variable is named `$PATH`. You can see it's contents in your current session by just typing `echo $PATH` in your terminal.

When a cron session is started for a job to be executed, this variable is not set.

To solve this issue, there are a few ways:

### Method 1:

Use full path names in your shell script and do not depend on the PATH variable for finding executables.

---

### Method 2:

Add the following at the beginning in your script (adjust if needed):

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

---

### Method 3:

(This method is generally discouraged)

Add the following line in your crontab (adjust if needed):

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

You can do `echo $PATH` in your terminal and copy the output in the above variable in the crontab.

Comment: For me aws was inside /usr/local and after specifying that inside the script, the cron job ran. Thanks a lot @ Sakis

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sakis your answer worked perfectly for me.
I was baffled why my scripts would run just fine from the command line but error out when run from cron. The reason was i was trying to use an executable from within bash that was not a recognized command due to lack of reference to a path. Now it's clear.
Did exactly this - no root or other sudo required.
From your own shell, echo $PATH. Copy this line and enter in your own cron (affects all jobs in that cron) or at the top of your script.

```
PATH=/home/myuser/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

And voila !